# Event handler of Dropdownlist inside Gridview

Tags: events, gridview, drop-down-menu, handler

I've added Dropdownlist in Gridview at RowDataBound event. The code is:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DropDownList ddlSeason = new DropDownList();

    ddlSeason.DataSourceID = "odsRoomSeason";
    ddlSeason.DataTextField = "SeasonTittle";
    ddlSeason.DataValueField = "SeasonID";
    ddlSeason.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddlSeason.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlSeason_SelectedIndexChanged);

    TableCell tcSeason= new TableCell();

    tcSeason.Controls.Add(ddlSeason);
    e.Row.Cells.AddAt(e.Row.Cells.Count, tcSeason);
}
```

The event handler I've added is:

```
protected void ddlSeason_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

But the problem is that the event handler function doesn't catch the event.
Please tell me how to write the correct event handler, also I need to get the row from which the Dropdownlist's event has fired.

Comment: Have you set AutoPostBack="True" for dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1):

have you managed to solve this in the meanwhile?

Make sure to **DataBind() the grid *before* the events are going to be fired**, because ASP.NET can only dispatch the event corrently if the dynamically created controls are there in that moment. The page life cycle after a post back looks roughly like this:

1. initialization
2. Page_Load()
3. process events
4. PreRender()
5. Render()

Therefore I had similar problems when I generated the dynamic controls on PreRender or later only, because events are processed before those steps. **It might be necessary to DataBind() the grid even twice** during the page life cycle: Once in Page_Load(), then after having processed events and updated the model, another DataBind() in PreRender() so to reflect the new model state.